# Multiple forms in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Not sure whether my database architecture is correct for rails. However below is my database architecture

## Database Relations

1. Each **User** instance has only one **PhoneBook** instance.
2. A single **Phonebook** instance can have multiple **Contact** instances
3. A single **Contact** instance can have multiple **Mobile** instances
4. A single **Contact** instance can have multiple **Email** instances

The question is how should I implement my controller and views if I want to add a new contact for a signed in user in his phonebook.

Comment: You should probably get a freelancer.

Comment: what you are asking is not a query/doubt but entire implementation ..which is not possible ...you can proceed ahead and can update this question if you face any trouble....your implementation is quite simple...you can give it a try....@pranav prashant

Comment: @Milind i'm new to Rails, just a week passed by. Working alone with no guide except for stack-overflow. Well the two answers below guided me a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do that with accepts_nested_attributes_for:, like a nested form

Comment: Thanks..
Could you just elaborate it for the views too?

Comment: check these links, that will help you http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1,  http://archives.ryandaigle.com/articles/2009/2/1/what-s-new-in-edge-rails-nested-attributes and http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html

Answer (score 0):

you could define the current user like so

```
controllers/application_controller.rb
def current_user
  @current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]
  # or find_by_authtoken!(...)
end
```

then you could do

```
controllers/phonebooks_controller.rb
def create
  @phonebook = Phonebook.create(phonebook_params)
  if @phonebook.save
    # redirects here
  end
end

.....

def phonebook_params
   params.require(:phonebook).permit(:phonebook_params....).merge(:user_id => current_user)
end
```

and in your contacts controller

```
controllers/contacts_controller.rb
def create
  @contact = Contact.create(contact_params)
  if @contact.save
    # redirects here
  end
end
.....
def contact_params
  params.require(:contact).permit(:contact_params....).merge(:user_id => current_user, :phonebook_id => current_user.phonebook)
end
```

Like that, you can use your forms in a simple manner, without having to generate routes like `/user/id/phonebook/id/contacts`

---

in addition to the links below the first answer, maybe have a look at [this](https://github.com/railstutorial/sample_app_rails_4/blob/master/app/views/users/new.html.erb) basic form. It it is not a direct answer to your question, but maybe it'll help you getting an idea of how a form could look like.

Comment: Thanks @The F
Could you just elaborate it for views too?